# Pygsheets append_table issue

Tags: python, pygsheets

I am at a loss. This is the final part of the script I am writing, and I can not get the data in the list 'Rows_Cleaned' to append to my spreadsheet. Now, the code works until the final line. I can print out the list 'Rows_Cleaned', but it will not append beyond the first row.

```
import pygsheets
json = path to json
spreadsht = json.open("Name of Spreadsheet")
gsheet = spreadsht.worksheet("title", tab name)
Rows_Cleaned = []

for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t in  zip(Site_ID,Site_Name,Location,ID,Last_Name,First_Name,Middle_Name,Staff_Type,Grade,Homeroom,Product,Tag,Charge_Type,Description,Charge_Notes,Issue_Date,Charge_Amount,Amount_Paid,Amount_Due,Satisfied_Date): 
#zipping a number of lists I am generating

Rows = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t]

if start_date <= p <= end_date: #Date check works
    Rows_Cleaned.append(Rows)

for data in Rows_Cleaned:
    gsheet.append_table(data, start='A2', end=None, dimension='ROWS', overwrite=False)
```

I have spent a few hours testing the rest of the code, making sure that the list comes out correctly, and that it prints, and even the .update_row() function works with Rows_Cleaned.

When I run this code, it appends the first index of the 'Rows_Cleaned' no problem, but when it attempts to advance to the second index, it spits out a "KeyError: 'tableRange'" error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong in this case. I would like for it to output each index of the list 'Rows_Cleaned' on a separate row.

I have also attempted to append the spreadsheet with a simplified 2D list, and it gives the same error (`Test_Data = [[123, 456,789],['test',123,'testing']])`.

The Data I'm actually working with inside a list looks something like this:

> (['="Number"', 'Name, 'Student', '="Number"', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name',
> None, '9', '="B228"', 'HP CHROMEBOOK 11MK G9 MODEL #349Y8UT',
> '="Number"', '23-24 Lost Device', None, None, '10/27/2023 9:49:26 AM',
> '200.0000', '200.0000', '0.0000', '10/27/2023 9:49:26 AM'],
> ['="128"', 'Name', 'Student', '="Number"', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name',
> None, '3', '="218"', 'HP CHROMEBOOK 11MK G9 MODEL #349Y8UT',
> '="Number"', '23-24 Chromebook Adapter', None, '7005758 - TESTING
> TOMORROW: Lost Chromebook charger', '10/23/2023 10:35:22 AM',
> '20.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '10/23/2023 10:35:22 AM'])

The fact that it starts to work and then errors out is driving me crazy. Thank you for any input given.

Also, the documentation for [pygsheets is here](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html)

Also, also, [an example of someone using this](https://youtu.be/jBYb12FRd4Q?si=tv0C9Bs3zZQKhv6X&t=302) in the same way I am trying to use it

Answer (score 0):

After another hour or so more researching I solved it:

```
gsheet.update_values(crange='A2',values=Rows_Cleaned,majordim='ROWS')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).